# Sql Server self join for employee manager relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, inner-join, self-join

```
EmpId   EmpName     ManagerId
1       Ramesh      NULL
2       Khiln       1
3       Khaushilk   1
4       Komal       2
5       Muffy       2
6       Jhon        3
7       Richa       3
8       Riya        4
```

my data

```
    empname     manager1  
1   Ramesh      NULL
2   Khiln       Ramesh 
3   Khaushilk   Ramesh 
4   Komal       Khiln
5   Muffy       Khiln
6   Jhon        Khaushilk
7   Richa       Khaushilk
8   Riya        Komal
```

now i want name of manager at lvel 2 such as manager of ramesh khiln khaushik...
howw cn i do it

Answer (score 1):

That's a self-join indeed:

```
select e.empname, m.empname as managername
from employees e
left join employees m on m.empid = e.managerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Following subquery will get you the desired result. You don't need to use a self join.

```
select emempid, e.empname, (select m.empname from employees m where m.empid = e.managerid) as managername
from employees e
```